# Installing Magento2 subfolder url

Tags: magento2

I've installed Magento into a subfolder /var/www/html/magento2
When I access it I need to type http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/magento2

How is it possible to navigate to site without using the subfolder ?
Is this related to .htaccess  file, I have not edited nor moved files around yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your `.htaccess` file in your **root folder(/var/www/html/)** with below code.

```
# Mod Rewrite
Options +FollowSymLinks  #Include this line if you are using Godaddy hosting
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)subfolder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subfolder/$1 [L]
```

In your case replace subfolder with magento2. Its working for me, check once.

Comment: The only item in html is a folder called magento2. So I copied .htaccess to html (leaving the original as is) and deleted  all content and added the above code. But now I receive a 500 error when I browse to either http://ip or http://ip/magento2.  Could this be permission related?

Comment: Don' copy the .htaccess file from magento2 subfolder. If you didn't find the file in /var/www/html, then create new one and use my code.

Comment: created new file nano .htaccess and added your code, changed two instances of 'subfolder' but same error.

Comment: Can you check the permissions of file and remove the two lines, `Mod Rewrite` and `Options +FollowSymLinks`, if you are not using the godaddy hosting.

Comment: I removed the godaddy hosting line and its now worked :)
When I browse to http://ip it now changes the url automatically to http://ip/magento2 and page renders. Is there a way to remove the magento2 from the url ? In mageto admin I found the following under 'Base URL' http://52.51.66.20/magento2/

Comment: Update the base URL's from ip/magento2 to IP only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49418/discussion-between-venu-joginpally-and-user32056).

Answer (score 0):

if you are using xampp then run your xampp control panel
click the button saying config
select apache( httpd.conf ) otherwise edit httpd.conf
find document root
replace

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
```

Those 2 lines

| C:/xampp/htdocs == current location for root |

|change C:/xampp/htdocs with any location you want|

save it and restart xampp

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a post about this link -> [post](https://jokiruiz.com/magento-2/how-to-run-magento-2-from-a-subdirectory/)

As everything goes through the /pub/ folder, you need to create /pub/subfolder and then change the relative path on the index.php file:

From:
`require realpath(DIR) . ‘/../app/bootstrap.php’;`

To:
`require realpath(DIR) . ‘/../../app/bootstrap.php’;`

It worked to me with Nginx and Magento 2.2