# Magento 2 Installation on root directory

Tags: magento2, permissions

Why do we have to install Magento 2 in Magento2 folder. Cannot we install Magento on root. How should i work on the ownership of Magento, if i install Magento 2 on root directory.

**PS: If i install my Magento2 (127.0.0.1/Magento2) inside a folder, is it possible to run Magento on 127.0.0.1 instead of 127.0.0.1/magento2**

Comment: Yes you can run your magento on 127.0.0.1 but for this you need to setup virtual host on Apache which will be represent 127.0.0.1 to your magento directory. Check this link how to create virtual host : https://in.godaddy.com/help/configure-apache-virtual-hosts-centos-7-17338

Comment: TY, what about Magento Folder Permissions  ?

Comment: You just need to do one thing 644 permission for all file and 755 for all folders, excluding pub and var. For pub and var you can use 777 or 775 .

Comment: is this independent of the user system, as mentioned in the magento docs. I am using dedicated server.

Comment: @Mek, You can redirect from 127.0.0.1/magento2 to 127.0.0.1 using .htaccess. Check the below link to change the .htaccess file. http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/148340/45181

Comment: doesn't .htaccess cause further delay in redirection. how can we set the magento2 folder as the main folder, so that we dont require redirections

Answer (score 1):

You can install magento anywhere you want on the server. The only thing you need to do is to define root folder in apache or nginx configuration so the server would search index.php file in the correct folder. So in order for you to use only 127.0.0.1 without /magento is to change vhost configuration. For nginx you need to set something like

```
root /var/www/magento2/pub;
```

For apache something like

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/magento2/pub"
```

Comment: Thanks, i need to just add DocumentRoot "/var/www/magento2/pub" in http.conf, what about the permissions of folder. How do i set them. I am using a dedicated server

Comment: Just to add to it, magento is running on shared server (very slow) but not working on dedicated