# Redirect Magento2 from subfolder to root folder

Tags: magento-2.2.5

I am new to Magento. Successfully installed/implemented Magento 2.2.5. However, I installed Magento as subfolder in root. And my cart shows as mydomainname.com/Magento. I want to change it so public does not see 'Magento' in my URL. One user sent me this post. [Installing Magento2 subfolder url](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148290/installing-magento2-subfolder-url). Based on this post, it appears that I only have to edit the .htaccess file. My .htaccess file has this code in the beginning:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mydomainname.com/Magento/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And the automatic Redirect code at the end:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomainname\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomainname\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.mydomainname\.com\/Magento\/" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomainname\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomainname\.com$
RewriteRule ^cgi\-bin\/commerce\.cgi$ "https\:\/\/www\.mydomainname\.com\/Magento\/" [R=301,L]
```

Should I change the code at the bottom too? Or simply change redirects, by removing word 'Magento' on Cpanel to auto generate it?

Do I have to copy index.php file too to root or leave it where it is?

How will Admin panel be accessed, after making above changes?

Additionally, I know I have to change the Web server configuration in Admin panel. Last time I did those changes, I lost my  Admin Panel access, and my website lost its images and formatting. I recall checking 'Use system Value' after making the changes in URL for both secure and unsecure.

Comment: See my other posting: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/244628/magento2-admin-panel-crashes-after-making-any-configuration-change-or-even-flush