# Magento2 Admin Panel crashes after making any configuration change or even flushing cache

Tags: magento2

I am encountering issue with Magento stability. 
Version 2.2.5. It is only a month old installation. 
When I login to Admin Panel, I can navigate to any screen/page/configuration. However, if I make any configuration changes and save, or even click on 'flush cache management', the admin panel screen closes and then I can not access Admin Panel because I get 404 page not found error. Additionally my website loses all its images, and the web content formatting changes.

I keep a copy of Magento folder, that I use to overwrite the exisitng Magento folder to recover from the above crashes.

Comment: How about comparing the files and folders before & after a click on "flush cache management"? You could, for example, create a local git repository, commit before flushing, and run a `git status` after the flushing. That might give you some hints about what happens during the flush.

Comment: Could you please share how to do that? I am new to both Magento and Github.

Comment: I have located how to create local github. Thanks for valuable input.

Comment: Great you found out! - Should be just a `git init`, followed by `git add .` and `git commit`.  Any outcomes?

Comment: Apologies for the late response. See my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I did go down the Git local repository path but abandoned it for couple of reasons. I did not share the entire background of what caused the crashes. We had implemented magento as subfolder under the root. I wanted to remove magento from our URL path.  Reading through different forums, it seemed pretty common request, and how to resolve it seemed pretty straight forward. I changed the Web URL configuration in Magento 2. Since then the Admin Panel had been crashing, and I had been restoring it as described here. I knew there was correlation between what we changed in the URL and Admin Panel crashes, but could not pin point. Yesterday, I did regression tweaking and  back tracking everything that we changed in Web URL. The key was that I had changed not just the Web Base URL (secure/unsecure) but also Web Base **Link** URL (secure/unsecure), and had unchecked 'Use system Value'. 
Also the core_config_data table entries reflected the URLs without the word magento, but the Admin Panel always had the word magento in its URL path, with the settings as stated above.

I checked the 'Use System Value', and saved the configuration. The Admin Panel came up like it used to. The system automatically deleted the entries for Web Base **Link** URL (secure/unsecure) in core_config_data table. Since then both the application and Admin Panel are stable. It resolved this issue, although the other posted issue remains: [Redirect Magento2 from subfolder to root folder](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/244014/redirect-magento2-from-subfolder-to-root-folder).

I belive that I can resolve it by simply editing the Web Base URL (secure/unsecure), and not touch the Base **Link** URL (secure/unsecure), or the 'use system value' checkbox.

What I am not clear is the significance of these fields **Base Link URL** and **Use System Value** .